# Getting SMTP Error "Could not connect to SMTP host" on server but working on my localhost

Tags: php, email, ssl, smtp, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer with gmail smtp, and its working for "tls" on my local xampp, but when i moved my project on server mail could not send and gives error: `SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.`

My Code is:

```
                     $mail = new PHPMailer();
                    $mail->IsSMTP();
                    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
                    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                    $mail->Port = 587; // Or 587
                    $mail->Username = $admin_email;
                    $mail->Password = $admin_password;
                    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
                    $mail->From = $admin_email;
                    // $mail->FromName= $from_name;
                    $mail->isHTML(true);
                    $mail->Subject = $subject;
                    $mail->Body = $body;
                    $mail->addAddress($emailTo);
                    if (!$mail->send()){
                    echo "error"; 
                      }
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: It's likely a firewall blocking the connection.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich so what i do to unblock

Comment: i debug it and got "error: MTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14"

Comment: Then it is gmail blocking you because of unusual activity of the account. Did you *log in via your web browser and then try again*  (with the same account, of course)?

Comment: i am saying, i am able to send mail via my localhost(my system xampp) with same code

Comment: Again, have you followed the instructions in the error message? These instructions are there for a reason.